# How to configure IIS to allow C++ .exe to run?

Tags: iis

how can we configure IIS to allow it to run/execute C++ .exe/binary files?

Explanation :

Hi,
I will try to elaborate it... 
I am having a C++ executable which is just a simple program which prints some HTML tags.
when I try to run this C++ binary using IIS like below :
http://localhost/htm_sample.exe
htm_sample.exe gets downloaded but i want to run this binary.

Could you please provide some help on this.

Thanks,
Pooja

Comment: Is your question answered orrrr

Answer (score 1):

If binaries automatically ran instead of being downloaded first for the user to run, this would be a massive vulnerability.

Imagine you go to a website with a HTML tag that redirects you to www.website.com/virus.exe and virus.exe automatically ran. They'd have a virus on your machine and literally all you did was visit their website. Regardless of browser, they'd have a virus on your machine. Massive security hole in most situations.

You may be able to mess around with the client if you are truly doing it on localhost, but you can't modify it elsewhere for other clients to auto run your binaries.

**HOWEVER** if you want it to execute on the **server end**, not the client end, and display the result of the exe being run from the server in your client's browser, there's a few options.

Make a regular PHP page and implement something like [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to run it. You would then be visiting a web page that would trigger the exe, not the exe itself.
You would have to install PHP.

I'm afraid I don't fully understand the use-case or actual implementation explained here however.
Why not just have a .html page with the HTML tags and serve that?

**if you only need it to work for localhost** you [can probably mess up your browser to the extent that it runs instead of downloading.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/809162)